# Making a translator using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'am trying to make a translator but it doesn't work, when I write something in
the textarea which is in my array, it must write in the other textarea "**Done**" but it doesn't.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function () {
    var $write = jQuery('textarea[name=edit]')
    var $read = jQuery('textarea[name=unedit]')
    var words = ["mouse", "head", "month"]
    var $button = jQuery('button')
    $button.click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <= words.length; i++) {
            if ($write == words[i]) {
                $read.text("Done")
            }
            else {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $read.text("Undone((")
                }, 1500)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: its working for me , check if you getting $write  or not,

Comment: I used val , it didn't work

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

`$write` is an object that references your textarea. You need to use `.val()` to retrieve its text, like this:

```
if ($write.val() == words[i]) {
```

Also the rest of your logic can be better, e.g. you now add multiple timers that keep writing "Undone((" which does not make much sense.